# Kong-manager access issue

Tags: kong, kong-ingress

we have installed Kong & all services are running fine.
when we are launching Kong manager from the terminal using curl command, In the browser it is throwing an error like "Failed to load resource: the server responded with the status of
404 ()" and the page is loading. can anyone please suggest on this.

Through postman, its giving 200 response with html script.
we have tried adding license. Json file. still facing the same error.